# The solution to the principal quintic via the Brioschi and Rogers-Ramanujan cfrac $R(q)$

Tags: polynomials, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, quintics

In this interesting [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4439694/4781), it quotes a paper that to write down the *complete* solution (not in radicals) of the general quintic, one would need "*a piece of paper as big as a large asteroid*". Probably an exaggeration, but perhaps we can reduce the size.

The *quartic* transformation that result in the Bring-Jerrard form can apply to *any* equation of deg $n>4$, and to undo everything later is a mess. But there is a transformation *unique to the quintic* which exploits its connection to the icosahedron and require only *square roots*, hence is much tidier.

---

**I. From general to principal quintic**

One first transforms the general quintic $P(x) = 0$ to principal form $P(y) = 0$ using a quadratic Tschirnhausen transformation $x^2+mx+n = y$. Thus, to recover the roots $x$ from $y$ need only solving a quadratic.

---

**II. Solution of the principal quintic**

Now that we have the principal form,

$$P(y)=y^5+5ay^2+5by+c = 0$$

then, like the Bring quintic, we can solve it using the *Dedekind eta function* $\eta(\tau)$ and *hypergeometric function* $_2F_1$ but without solving any cubic or quartic at all. Instead, the [*Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_continued_fraction#Relation_to_modular_forms) $R(q)$ appears. It can be done in just $9$ steps.

First, solve the quadratic for any root $\lambda$,

$$(a^4 + a b c - b^3)\lambda^2 - (11a^3b - a c^2 + 2b^2 c)\lambda + (64a^2b^2 - 27a^3c - b c^2) =    0\tag1$$

then define $e,f$ as,

$$e = \frac{-8a \lambda^3 - 72b \lambda^2 - 72c \lambda + g a^2}{a \lambda^2 + b \lambda + c} \tag2$$

$$f = \frac{1}{1728 - g} \tag3$$

$$g = \frac{(a \lambda^2 - 3b \lambda - 3c)^3}{a^2(a c \lambda - b^2\lambda - b c)} \tag4$$

Let $q = e^{2\pi i\tau}$ and the principal quintic roots $y$ are,

$$y = \frac{ez+\lambda}{f^{-1}z^2-3}\tag5$$

$$z = \pm\sqrt{\frac{-f(u^2 + 4)(u^2 - 2u - 4)^2}{u^5 + 5 u^3 + 5u - 11}}\tag{6a}$$

Or alternatively,

$$\quad z = \pm\left(\frac{1}{R(q)}+R(q)\right)\sqrt{\frac{-f(u^2 - 2u - 4)^2}{v - 11}}\tag{6b}$$

$$u = \frac{1}{R(q)}-R(q) = \frac{\eta(\tau/5)}{\eta(5\tau)}+1\tag{7a}$$

$$\quad v = \frac{1}{R^5(q)}-R^5(q) = \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(5\tau)}\right)^6+11\tag{7b}$$

$$\qquad\qquad \tau=\tau_k = k+ \frac{_2F_1\big(\tfrac16,\tfrac56,1,1-\beta\big)}{_2F_1\big(\tfrac16,\tfrac56,1,\beta\big)}\sqrt{-1}, \quad (k = 0,1,2,3,4) \tag8$$

$$\qquad\qquad 4\beta^2-4\beta+\frac{1728f}{1728f-1} = 0\quad(\text{any root}\;\beta)\\ \tag9$$

Steps $1-5$ transform the principal quintic into the Brioschi as described in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1568763/4781) and can be found in Duke's and Tóth's "*[The Splitting of Primes in Division Fields of Elliptic Curves](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ewdduke/preprints/splitting.pdf)*" in page 10. (*Note*: There is a stumbling block in Step 4 when $a=0$, but one can get around that by redefining the first four steps.) The steps afterwards are mine and a more efficient version of [this 2015 post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1425435/4781).

Thus, by passing through the Brioschi quintic, it seems one may not need an asteroid-sized piece of paper after all.

---

**III. Example**

Given,

$$y^5+5y^2+10y+2=0$$

so $a,b,c = 1,2,2.\,$ Solving $(1)$, we choose $v = \tfrac{1}{3}\big({-17} + \sqrt{871}\big)$ and get,

$$e = \tfrac{16}{27}\big(5071 - 179\sqrt{871}\big)$$

$$f = \tfrac{1}{43312^2}\big(615193 + 20894 \sqrt{871}\big)$$

Substituting those into Steps $5$-$9$, and choosing the correct sign of $z$, we find the five roots $y$.

---

**IV. Question**

Note that Step $6\text{a}$ solves the Brioschi quintic,

$$z^5-10fz^3+45f^2z-f^2 = 0$$

$$z = \pm\sqrt{\frac{-f(u^2 + 4)(u^2 - 2u - 4)^2}{u^5 + 5 u^3 + 5u - 11}}\tag{6a}$$

**Q.** But is there a way to simplify the expression in $u$ under the square root sign? Or solve for $z$ without square roots at all? (The polynomials are so familiar I feel the solution must already have been tackled by Brioschi, Klein, or their contemporaries.)

**Update:** As pointed out by @dxiv and @ParamanandSingh in the comments, we can indeed simplify the root $z$ as,

$$\quad z = \pm\sqrt{-f\;}\,(u^2 - 2u - 4)\left(\frac{1}{R(q)}+R(q)\right) \left(\frac{\eta(5\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}\right)^{3}\tag{6b}$$

where $u = \frac{1}{R(q)}-R(q) = \frac{\eta(\tau/5)}{\eta(5\tau)}+1,$ so only $f$ remains under the square root, confirming my belief that $z$ must have a simpler form. (But this can't be the solution found by Brioschi or his contemporaries since they lived before Ramanujan.)

Comment: Even the formulas for cubics and quartics are so complicated that they are usually not used in practice. This will be the case even more for a quintic. And since it cannot be generally solved by radicals anyway , it is barely worth the effort to establish a procedure.

Comment: I once heard of Bring radicals (claimed to allow to solve a general quintic) , maybe this approach is easier.

Comment: @Peter From principal to Bring quintic needs a quartic transformation, so to undo it would be a complicated mess. But this method needs only square roots so it’s doable. I guess it is just the desire to know if something can be done. And this method also implies the quintic is solvable by the Rogers-Ramanujan cfrac, so that in itself is notable.

Comment: Does [Thomae’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_formula#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Thomae's%20formula%20is,Mumford%201984%2C%20section%208) apply? It does not require any transformations

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII In terms of $R=R(q)$ the first factor in the numerator turns into a square $u^2+4 = \left(R + \dfrac{1}{R}\right)^2$. But the denominator $u^5 + 5 u^3 + 5u - 11 = R^5 - \dfrac{1}{R^5} - 11$ looks no nicer.

Comment: @dxiv: the last expression involving $R^5$ is well known and has a nice form in terms of Dedekind eta function.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you for the nudge (which also made me realize that I got a couple of signs wrong in the very last expression). If I am not mistaken, eq. $(3)$ in your post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4000258/relation-between-rogers-ramanujan-continued-fraction-and-j-invariant) shows that the denominator is a perfect square in terms of $\eta$, then.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII That was the low-hanging fruit, I guess ;-) because, to be honest, I have not followed all the deeper steps. I know that's no news to you, but for reference [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922221/algebraic-relations-between-gq-and-hq), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3835032/closed-form-of-frace-frac-pi51-frace-pi1-frace-2-pi1/) look to be related, too.

Comment: @dxiv I just tested your relations. Yes, it's, \begin{align}u^2+4 &= \left(\frac{1}{R}+R\right)^2\\ u^5+5u^3+5u-11 &= \left(\frac{1}{R^5}-R^5-11\right) = \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(5\tau)}\right)^6\end{align} (correcting your signs for the second) so both are squares.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thomae's formula is too complicated and exotic that I can't even find an example for the quintic. Maybe one can start with one-parameter or two-parameter functions, for the latter like the Appell or Kampé de Fériet functions. I see you have posts for the second. Do you have an example of an Appell or Kampé that is a root of a 4-term sextic?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I have updated the post with yours and dxiv's insights. I should have guessed that both $R(q)$ and $R^5(q)$ would appear.

Comment: @Peter: I believe the formulae "grow" at a slightly exponential-ish rate; i.e. each one is a few times as "big" as the previous. The jump from "fits on a page when wrapped, but at still-legible font" (Ferrari's quartic formula, IIRC) to now "needs so much paper it covers a big asteroid" (billions? trillions? of pages) seems extraordinary. Hence to ask if we can soften it, without say just getting overly "generous" in the kind of non-radical solution functions we admit (otherwise you can just define a function $\mathrm{Root}$ and...).

Answer (score -1):

Too long for a comment :

We can play with mixing nested radicals and continued fraction :

### Example

Let :

$$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cdot\cdot\cdot}}}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cdot\cdot\cdot}}}}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cdot\cdot\cdot}}}}}}}}$$

Then $x$ is near from the solution of :

$$x^{2}\left(1+x+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x+1}}\right)-1\simeq 0$$

Or :

$$x^{5}+5x^{4}+8x^{3}+4x^{2}-3x-2\simeq 0$$

Then use Newton's method and the general solution of the quartic .

Hope it helps .

Edit : I misread the question here there is no square roots but square :

we have :

$$\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(1+1\right)^{2}}\right)^{2}}\right)^{2}}\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(1+1\right)}\right)^{2}}\right)^{2}}\right)^{2}}}=x$$

Then we have :

$$x\left(\left(1+x\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}}\right)-1\simeq 0$$

Or :

$$x^{5}+4x^{4}+7x^{3}+5x^{2}+x-2=0$$

Then use Newton's method and quartic general formula .

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Is it satisfying for you ?